Connecting to Milvus instance inside an rdd map function fails
So I have a list of tuples, List[Tuple[str,List[float]] , and I am trying to parallelize it and insert into a Milvus instance using just the PyMilvus connector.
rdd.foreachPartition(insert_records)

And my insert_records() looks like this:
def insert_records(data):
    connection_alias_in_rdd = "default123"
    connections.connect(alias=connection_alias_in_rdd, db_name="default", host="1.2.3.4", port="12345", user='rootuser',
                        password='strongpassword')
    print(connections.list_connections())
    if connections.has_connection(connection_alias_in_rdd):
        collection_name = "sample_collection"
        collection_in_rdd: Collection = Collection(collection_name, using=connection_alias_in_rdd)
    collection_in_rdd.insert(records)
    collection_in_rdd.flush()
    connections.disconnect(alias=connection_alias_in_rdd)

So whats happening here is that the connection is getting created using the .connect(), which is later validated with the if statement, and then getting a Collection instance fails with the error:
 File "/Users/test.py", line 94, in insert_records
    collection_in_rdd: Collection = Collection(collection_name, using=connection_alias_in_rdd)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/orm/collection.py", line 116, in __init__
    conn = self._get_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/orm/collection.py", line 172, in _get_connection
    return connections._fetch_handler(self._using)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymilvus/orm/connections.py", line 540, in _fetch_handler
    raise ConnectionNotExistException(message=ExceptionsMessage.ConnectFirst)
pymilvus.exceptions.ConnectionNotExistException: <ConnectionNotExistException: (code=1, message=should create connection first.)>

I am unable to wrap my head around this - the connection already exists, and even though the map function might be executing in an isolated environment, it should still be able to use the client side connection that's already created.
What is that I could be missing here?
